# Obtaining data from third party apps

Tags: android, ios, mobile

Apologies if this is too general a question.

I would like to know if inn principle it is feasible for an app to be developed that would be able to access data collected by other apps on the users phone.

The user would of course consent to this but in general would it be feasible to build an app that could e.g. gather data regarding how many miles a user had logged in a running app, or how many purchases they had made in a shopping app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible. Many applications have so-called APIs. Many apps or services like Facebook, Youtube, etc. have such an API. You should familiarize yourself with JSON and these APIs. Here is an explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s7wmiS2mSXY&t=129s